# How can I get annotations (neatly) outside the convex hull?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, convex-hull

I have developed a bit of code to automatically generate an equilateral n-dimensional polygon:

```
# Create equilateral n-dimensional polygon

def polygon(side, radius=1, rotation=0, translation=None):
    import math
    vertex = 2 * math.pi / side

    points = [
        (math.sin(vertex * i + rotation) * radius,
         math.cos(vertex * i + rotation) * radius)
         for i in range(side)]

    if translation:
       points = [[sum(pair) for pair in zip(point, translation)]
                  for point in points]
return np.array(points)
```

Now, I want to put labels neatly to the **outside** corners of this n-dimensional polygon. In the following example I have created a hexagon with radius 10, centered around (3,3).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pol = polygon(7, 10, 0, [3,3])
hull = ConvexHull(pol)
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', "L", 'M', 
          'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(pol[simplex,0], pol[simplex,1], 'k-')
plt.plot(pol[:,0], pol[:,1], 'gs', ms=10)
if labels is not None:
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        if i <= len(pol)-1:
            plt.annotate(label, xy=(pol[:,0][i],pol[:,1][i]), xytext=(0, 8), 
textcoords='offset points', ha="center", va="bottom")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, as the figure shows, only point A, B, and F lay neatly outside the hexagon. Is there a systematic way to annotate the labels to the outside corner of the polygon (hexagon in this case), no matter the dimension *n*? Thanks in advance!

[Plot of hexagon with wrongly placed annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5zld.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's look at the special case of a n-dimensional regular polygon.

For this, you can just put the annotations on the vertices of a slightly larger polygon (I used 1.2 times the original radius).

Below is the full code and result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

r = 10  # radius
center = [3, 3]
pol = polygon(7, r, 0, center)
pol2 = polygon(7, 1.2*r, 0, center)  # for annotations
hull = ConvexHull(pol)
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', "L", 'M', 
          'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(pol[simplex,0], pol[simplex,1], 'k-')
plt.plot(pol[:,0], pol[:,1], 'gs', ms=10)
if labels is not None:
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        if i <= len(pol)-1:
            plt.annotate(label, xy=(pol2[i,0], pol2[i,1]), xytext=(0, 0), 
                         textcoords='offset points', ha="center", va="center")
plt.xlim(center[0] - 1.5*r, center[0] + 1.5*r)
plt.ylim(center[1] - 1.5*r, center[1] + 1.5*r)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: Regular Polygon with annotations]

Now, let's look at a general convex hull. An easy solution would be the following:

1. For each simplex S, calculate the mid point M of its neighbouring two simplices (called N_1 and N_2). We know this midpoint must be in the interior of the convex hull.

   ```
   (N_1, N_2) = hull.neighbors(S)
   M = (pol[N_1] + pol[N_2]) / 2
   ```
2. Draw the line from M to S, and take the new point M_ext which is on the line, so that S is equidistant to M and M_ext, but with M_ext being on the other side. We know that M_ext is definitely, in that case.

   ```
   M_ext = pol[S] + (pol[S] - M)
   ```

   You could potentially normalize it, so that the annotations are the same distance to the simplex (e.g. using numpy.linalg.norm). In my code I also multiplied by a constant factor, so that the text does not overlap with the vertices.

   ```
   M_ext = pol[S] + (pol[S] - M) / np.linalg.norm(pol[S]-M)
   ```

Again full code & result below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

r = 10  # radius
center = [3, 3]
pol = polygon(7, r, 0, center)
pol2 = polygon(7, 1.2*r, 0, center)  # for annotations
hull = ConvexHull(pol)
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', "L", 'M', 
          'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(pol[simplex,0], pol[simplex,1], 'k-')
plt.plot(pol[:,0], pol[:,1], 'gs', ms=10)
if labels is not None:
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        if i <= len(pol)-1:
            S = i
            (N_1, N_2) = hull.neighbors[S]
            M = (pol[N_1] + pol[N_2]) / 2
            M_ext = pol[S] + (pol[S] - M) / np.linalg.norm(pol[S] - M) * 0.2*r
            plt.annotate(label, xy=M_ext, xytext=(0, 0), 
textcoords='offset points', ha="center", va="center")
plt.xlim(center[0] - 1.5*r, center[0] + 1.5*r)
plt.ylim(center[1] - 1.5*r, center[1] + 1.5*r)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: Polygon with annotations #2]

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, code and theoretical reasoning! Your code almost works, only for **n>8** the labels on the second polygon fall outside the graph limits. I will try to tweak this myself, based upon your solution.

Comment: Ow wait, I implemented something wrong. My bad. It works great now!

Comment: Glad it is of help!